# Type 'IncomingHttpHeaders' is not assignable to type 'BusboyHeaders'

Tags: node.js, typescript, busboy

I am using busboy in typescript/Node project for file uploading, In every documentation of busboy
they initialize it with request headers, but I'm getting this error **Type 'IncomingHttpHeaders' is not assignable to type 'BusboyHeaders'.**
here is my code

```
import { NextFunction, Request, Response, Router } from "express";
import Busboy = require('busboy');
import * as path from "path";
import * as fs from "fs";

export class FileUploader {

    // method for file upload to server.
    public upload(req: Request, res: Response, next?: NextFunction) {
        const busboy = Busboy({ headers: req.headers });
        

        busboy.on("file", function (fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) {

            // path to file upload
            const saveTo = path.join((path.join(__dirname, "/../images/" + filename)));

            file.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(saveTo));
        });

        busboy.on("finish", function () {
            res.status(200).json({ "message": "File uploaded successfully." });
        });
        req.pipe(busboy);

    }
}
```

**getting error on the following line**

```
const busboy = Busboy({ headers: req.headers });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Busboy just requires `content-type` (lowercase) as the header field. Just provide the express request content type for busboy:

```
import * as Busboy from 'busboy';

    const busboy = new Busboy({
        headers: {
            'content-type': event.headers['content-type'] || event.headers['Content-Type'],
        }
    });
```